# toggle active class on click

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

I want to toggle the 'active' class on a list of elements (filters) when one of them is clicked, but I'm seeking a more concise way to do it without using two nested loops.

This is what I tried it works fine but I feel nesting a loop inside it's parent loop feels wrong to me

JS

```
filters.forEach(elem => {

  elem.addEventListener('click', () => {

    

    filters.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('active'));

    item.classList.add('active');

  })

})
```

HTML

```
<div class="filters">

        <button id="all" class="active">All</button>

        <button id="active">Active</button>

        <button id="completed">Completed</button>

      </div>
```

Comment: See the linked question that shows how to do this with event delegation instead of a loop.

Comment: `item.classList.add('active');` should be `elem.classList.add('active')`

Comment: Instead of using `button` elements, use a radio group, which has that behavior by default.